# AMD Radeon HD 6700M on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

I have a problem with my notebook.

I have just upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1, and I got my graphics cards messed up. I have two of them, an integrated Intel one and an external AMD one. I want to switch to AMD (because it's more powerful), but I don't know how. I used to be able to switch between them in AMD Catalyst Control Center (Google tells the same), but now the button to switch between graphics cards is gone. AMD CCC acts like the AMD graphics card is missing, but device dispatcher shows that both cards are functional and have drivers up to date.

I tried manually installing drivers for the AMD card, but it didn't help. I tried a lot of things, and the only solution it seems I have is to manually switch to the AMD card with some console magic, or fix something with the AMD card with good old console magic. (dxdiag says that the Intel graphics card is being used)

Most of my notebook specs are here, in [my AMD forums post](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=448&threadid=167140) (AMD forums are not really helpful). Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old thread, but for the folks with the same problem it seems that now ATI started to support switchable legacy graphics with their latest 13.11 9.2 beta drivers

More info here: http://leshcatlabs.net/2013/11/11/amd-enables-legacy-switchable-graphics-support/

> It has come to our attention that AMD has finally made changes to the way their official drivers install for switchable systems. I.E As far as we know, there is NO need for Modded 13.11 beta 9.2 AMD drivers that can be found on certain forums as the Official AMD release works out of the box for a certain percentage of switchable Laptops.
>
> This means that as of 13.11 beta 9.2 AMD has incorporated switchable
>   parameters into the kernel adding support for devices which they
>   inherently did not want to support such as the 5xxx and 6xxxm series.

Beta drivers download link: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows+8+-+64

I hope that this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try the Beta-Driver for Windows 8.1 from here: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalystOpenGL43BetaDriver.aspx

**AMD Mobility Catalyst OpenGL 4.3 Beta Driver for Windows**

http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/AMD_Catalyst_Mobility_Win8.1_Release_Preview-13.15.100.1.exe

> **AMD Product Compatibility:**
>
> ```
> AMD Mobility Radeon HD 6000M Series
> ```

Comment: Didn't help. I tried uninstalling my current AMD soft and installing this, but installer doesn't install anything and show me a somewhat empty error log. Then I tried installing this ontop of this: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalystWIN8-1PreviewDriver.aspx
It installed succesfully, updated the drivers, but still no result. CCC is not detecting my graphics card.

Comment: which laptop do you use?

Comment: try this one: http://leshcatlabs.net/2013/06/11/leshcats-catalyst-13-6-beta-2-uniflfor-amdintel-powered-laptops/

Comment: also try the 13.8 beta driver: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-8WINBetaDriver.aspx